# Comprobar si el almacenamiento de la ruta de la imagen fue correcta en codeigther

Tags: php, array, codeigniter, archivo

Necesito cargar o almacenar unos archivos, el cual guardo la ruta en la base de datos y ese archivo lo mando a una carpeta con una ruta principal. 
El error viene cuando hago mi subida de archivo, me elmacena pero no me chequea que de verdad este bien, para ello le coloque que al subir el archivo el estado envie un check verde si lo cargo correctamente.

Pero me sale este error después de tanto indagar por que no me cargar el array:
Array ( [name] => Array ( [0] => CONSOLIDADOREQUERIMIENTO.docx ) [type] => Array ( [0] => application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document ) [tmp_name] => Array ( [0] => C:\xampp\tmp\php9AE1.tmp ) [error] => Array ( [0] => 0 ) [size] => Array ( [0] => 131975 ) ) 11

Les dejo el codigo para que puedan entender a lo que me refiero:
    public function others_data() { //Recarga de otros archivos adjuntos (DETALLES DE GESTIÓN)
        $nro = count($_FILES["archivo_otros"]["name"]);

```
    for ($i = 0; $i < $nro; $i++) {
        print_r($_FILES["archivo_otros"]);
        $file_name = $_FILES["archivo_otros"]["name"][$i];
        $file_size = $_FILES["archivo_otros"]["size"][$i];
        $file_type = $_FILES["archivo_otros"]["type"][$i];
        if ($file_name != "") {
            $nombre_archivo = $file_name;

            if (!file_exists('./files/others/' . $nombre_archivo)) {
                mkdir('./files/others/', 0777, true);
            }
            $path = "files/others";

            copy($_FILES["archivo_otros"]['tmp_name'][$i], $path . '/' . $nombre_archivo);

            $datos = array(
                'nombre' => $nombre_archivo,
                'ruta' => 'C:/xampp/htdocs/cnr/' . $path . '/',
                'tipo' => 'Otros',
                'detalle_actividad_id' => $_POST['idDetalle']
            );

            $this->submit_model->form_insert($datos, 'archivos_adjuntos');
        } else {
            $errors = array('error' => 'Error con: {$file_name}');
        }
    }
    $where=array(
        'field' => 'detalle_actividad_id',
        'condition' => $_POST['idDetalle']);
    $datos_2['estatus_control'] = 'En Trámite';
    $this->submit_model->form_update($datos_2, 'control_actividades', null, $where);
    $url = base_url('process/index') . '?cty=' . $_POST['cty'] . '&cpy=' . $_POST['cpy'] . '&prc=' . $_POST['prc'] . '&lab=' . $_POST['lab'] . '&sol=' . $_POST['app'];
    //redirect($url, "refresh");
}
```

Comente la linea donde se encuentra el refresh para saber que me estaba dan

Answer (score 0):

Prueba este código:

```
public function others_data() { 

    //Recarga de otros archivos adjuntos (DETALLES DE GESTIÓN)
    $nro = count($_FILES["archivo_otros"]["name"]);


    echo "<pre>"; print_r( $_FILES[ "archivo_otros" ]); echo "</pre>"; //Traza

    for ($i = 0; $i < $nro; $i++) {
        //print_r($_FILES["archivo_otros"]);
        $file_name = $_FILES["archivo_otros"]["name"][$i];
        $file_size = $_FILES["archivo_otros"]["size"][$i];
        $file_type = $_FILES["archivo_otros"]["type"][$i];

        if ( $file_name != "" ) {
            $path = "files/others/";
            if (!is_dir( $path )) {
                mkdir('./files/others/', 0777, true);
            }

            $file_path = $path . $file_name;
            echo "File path: " . $file_path . "<br>"; //Traza
            copy( $_FILES["archivo_otros"]['tmp_name'][$i], $file_path );

            $datos = array(
                'nombre' => $file_name,
                'ruta' => 'C:/xampp/htdocs/cnr/' . rtrim ( $path , "/" ),
                'tipo' => 'Otros',
                'detalle_actividad_id' => $_POST['idDetalle']
            );

            $res = $this->submit_model->form_insert($datos, 'archivos_adjuntos');
            var_dump( $res ); //trace

        } else {
            $errors = array('error' => 'Error con: {$file_name}');
        }
    }
    die( "stop" ); //Trace

    $where=array(
        'field' => 'detalle_actividad_id',
        'condition' => $_POST['idDetalle']);
    $datos_2['estatus_control'] = 'En Trámite';
    $this->submit_model->form_update($datos_2, 'control_actividades', null, $where);
    $url = base_url('process/index') . '?cty=' . $_POST['cty'] . '&cpy=' . $_POST['cpy'] . '&prc=' . $_POST['prc'] . '&lab=' . $_POST['lab'] . '&sol=' . $_POST['app'];
    //redirect($url, "refresh");
}
```

He introducido trazas para ver por donde va, con un comentario de `//trace` al final de la línea, deberás eliminarlas después. La Ultima finaliza el script para saber si llegas hasta ese punto sin errores, donde ya deberá haber guardado los ficheros.

Comment: me sale lo siguiente:

Comment: Array(
    [name] => Array(
            [0] => Informe Situacion Proyecto Normas y Registros  Noviembre.docx
        )
    [type] => Array(
            [0] => application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document
        )
    [tmp_name] => Array
        (
            [0] => C:\xampp\tmp\php7247.tmp
        )

    [error] => Array
        (
            [0] => 0
        )

    [size] => Array
        (
            [0] => 196103
        )

)

File path: files/others/Informe Situacion Proyecto Normas y Registros Noviembre.docx
1bool(true) stop

Comment: La instrucción *$this->submit_model->form_insert(...)* te devuelve TRUE. Lo que se supone que debe hacer, debió de hacerlo. Y llegas al *die()* sin errores, entonces esa parte debe estar bien. Comenta esa línea, para continuar la ejecución.
Algo que puede dar problemas son los espacios con los nombres de archivo, recomiendo sustituirlos por guiones bajos, así como eñes, diéresis y acentos. Deberías usar un filtro para sustituir estos caracteres para los nombres de archivo.

Comment: no me carga la imagen me hace la busqueda y todo pero cuando le coloco el refresh y vuelvo a consultar el boton no me sale la imagen cargada previamente.

Comment: como estaba antes la respuesta era la siguiente:

Comment: como estaba antes la respuesta era la siguiente: Array
(
    [name] => Array
        (
            [0] => 4.png
        )
    [type] => Array
        (
            [0] => image/png
        )
    [tmp_name] => Array
        (
            [0] => C:\xampp\tmp\phpA446.tmp
        )
    [error] => Array
        (
            [0] => 0
        )
    [size] => Array
        (
            [0] => 642312
        )
)
File path: files/others/4.png
11

Comment: ¿Has comprobado fisicamente si el fichero se guarda donde quieres? Si no es así, el problema debe ser al mover el fichero temp a su lugar de almacenamiento

Comment: Documentación de CodeIgniter para subir ficheros: https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/file_uploading.html?highlight=upload%20files